# How to Do BusinessHour(Time) Calculations in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Iam Very new to  Business Hour Time Calculations @ Angularjs

> My Aim is to Calculate the Difference between  Current Browser Time
>   and Close time   in Angular Front End in form of Elements  .. Its Been really Confusing.I
>   Worked With Grails ,JavaScript  which is Straight and easy ... Time Is
>   Being Killed  in AngularJs @ Business Hour Calculations :-(

Let me Show What i Did

Angular Controller:-

Function to Compare current day with  business Hours day for instantaneous Timings display

```
    $scope.currentBusinessHourDayTimings=function(){
        $scope.todaydate = new Date();
         var dateobj = new Date();
       // Fetching Current day and  Timing in Hours Minutes 
        var hours = dateobj.getHours(); // 6
        var minutes=dateobj.getMinutes();

        $scope.Hours=hours+':'+minutes;

        $scope.filterdate = $filter('date')( $scope.todaydate, 'EEEE');
        var sliceday =$scope.filterdate;
        $scope.today=sliceday.substring( 0, 3).toLowerCase();

    };
```

Angular View Where i need to do some magic to display In **HH:MM** Going to Close

**Here i How can i Show the Difference By Performing Subtraction to Current Time and  Closing time  in Hours and Minutes ?**

Note :- In Below Code 21:00 would render From Json object

```
<span>
                               <span  ng-if=" Hours < 21:00" ><b><i > Delivery Will Close in HH:MM </i></b></span>
                                <span  ng-if=" Hours > 21:00 " ><b><i > Delivery Closed   </i></b></span>
                                <span  class="land_sep">|</span>
                             <span ng-if=" Hours > 21:00" >Take out closed </span>
                                             <span ng-if=" Hours < 21:00" >Take out Closing  Close in HH:MM </span>

                            </span>
```

Guys Honestly I Have No Idea On Time Calculation Part

Could you please any One Help/Suggest me a Solution For this Scenario.

Thanks A Lot In Advance !!

Comment: Any cons arguments about using an external library like [momentJS](http://momentjs.com) ? Hugh time saver about such manipulation.

Comment: I agree with sebastienbarbier. momentJS will make your life easier :)

Comment: Actually  no dude i am not using any Dependencies .. Actually i need to Compare Current time to Event Closing time and I need to Display that Time Difference .. in Angular View Spans

Comment: I see this question is still open, could you try using momentJS and find a solution ? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [momentJS](http://momentjs.com) could save you a lot of time.

```
Relative Time
moment("20111031", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); // 3 years ago
moment("20120620", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); // 3 years ago
moment().startOf('day').fromNow();        // a day ago
moment().endOf('day').fromNow();          // in 2 hours
moment().startOf('hour').fromNow();       // 23 minutes ago
```

Code is good looking, easy to read/understand, i18n ... and very easy to customize.

### MomentJS with Angular ?

There is a GitHub project [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) which works very well. You will not regret using it ;)